# How to store and retrieve nested values in a Vuex Store with Vue.js in a Survey application?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, reactive, survey

I have a module in Vuex with the following state:

```
const state = {
    questions: [{
        label: "Do you have a great day?",
        answers: [{
            label: "I had struggles"
        }, {
            label: "Some other answer"
        }, {
            label: "Maybe three answers"
        }]
    }, {
        label: "Another question about something?",
        answers: [{
            label: 'Some answer'
        }, {
            label: 'This is also an answer'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Now in a view ( I use VueRouter ), I will retrieve one question, show the answers. Then the people can answer the question with a 'input[type="range"]' from 1 to 10.

What is the best way to store this values?

So I will have some routing like:

```
/questions/1
/questions/2
```

In the end I will count up the results per question and show some totals.

On the questions page there is a next and a previous button.

Thank you for your help, I'm a little bit stuck on this part for a while right now.

Ronald.

Comment: Do you have a key (or id) for the questions and answers? You could create maps and then create an association list for responses.

Comment: What do you want to do with the results?  If you're averaging them, you can just create a variable that tracks the sum and divides by the number of answers.  If you want to show how many people chose any particular answer, you could create a variable that just goes up by 1 every time that answer is chosen (using @click for the submit button)?

Comment: Actually I don't have a key. Can you give me an example for when I have one? I could iterate over the questions maybe and add the index as id / key?!

Comment: @nbixler I just want to show a average page, so count up de values of each answer per question and show the average. Say you answered the answers in question 1 with 3,5,8,4, then I will show for that question in the end the average of ( 3 + 5 + 8 + 4 ) / 4 = 5;

Answer (score 0):

Based on my  understanding of your comments, I would create a base array, and then use @click on the next button (checking to make sure they answered all the questions) to add those inputted values to the base array.  So your masterArray would be [ [user1's answers], [user2's answers], ...] Then you can find an average by iterating through masterArray and summing user1[questionIndex] + user2[questionIndex] ...

So user one submits answers "3, 6, 4, 2, 1" This array becomes the first array in masterArray.  User two submits answers "3, 2, 56, 3, 6"  Now masterArray looks like { [3, 6, 4, 2, 1], [3, 2, 56, 3, 6] }  To find the average of question 1 you just plug in (this is pseudocode) `masterArray[0[0]] + masterArray[1[0]] / masterArray.length`

(If you're hoping to store it long term, then you'll need to look at how your server stores data which is a different question).

Comment: Thank you for your response!

This is indead a way. But do you suggest to 'generate' the questions with answer arrays? Because now I've the questions with answers hardcoded in the store.

When I load the page, I loop through the questions, but I dont have a model or a place to store the answers at that moment.